# How do you link to the profile page of the author of a post?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm assisting a client with a custom Wordpress theme where the previous developer linked to the blog author's profile within each current post. Presently, it is not linking to the author's profile and I'm attempting to fix the issue.

Below is the code that I've attempted to link to the author's profile of the current post, but it has not working.

```
   <?php $username = get_userdata( $post->post_author ); ?>
   <?php print '<div class="header-author-share"><span class="author vcard"> <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $post->post_author); ?>">'.$avatar.'<span class="author-information">' . esc_html(get_the_author() ) . '</span></a><span class="date-time-reading"> . 
   <span class="post-date-spn">'.get_the_date('M 
   jS',get_the_ID()).'</span><span class="post-date- 
   time">'.do_shortcode('[rt_reading_time postfix="min" 
   postfix_singular="min"]').' read</span></span></span></div>';?>
```

I expecting the "author-information" to be linked to the current author's profile page. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `<?php echo` is of course nonsense, when you already _are_ inside a string.

Comment: That second line is really ugly and hard to read. Rather than print the `div` tag in the print/echo, keep the PHP block closed and print the HTML natively and only echo the function calls.

Comment: @misorude So should I just fetch the url and then link it within the a tag?

Something like this:
<?php $linkaddress = get_author_posts_url( $post->post_author ); ?> <?php print '<a class="url fn n" href='.$link_address.'><span class="author-information"></span></a>'; ?>

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

As pointed out in a comment below your question, you have a syntax string error. Try fixing this first.

---

You can try fetching the info using this wordpress function:

```
$authorDescr = get_the_author_meta( 'user_description', $post->post_author );
```

Then simply add `$authorDescr` to the content of the element.

Comment: So something to this effect would add a link to the authors profile on the span tag for "author-information"?

 <?php $linkaddress = get_author_posts_url( $post->post_author ); ?>
  
 <?php 
 print '<a class="url fn n" href='.$link_address.'><span class="author-information"></span></a>';
 ?>